# Apache basic auth with SetEnvIf bug

Tags: apache, .htaccess, basic-authentication, setenvif

I have a problem with apache 2.4 .htaccess configuration. My config example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^(?i).*/admin(/.*)?$ require_auth=true 
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secure area"
AuthUserFile /xxx/.admin_htpasswd
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all   
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

The idea is to ask a password for requests to urls which contains "/admin" string. So if I go to www.mysite.com/admin the password is required and if I go to www.mysite.com/news the password is not required.

But there is a strange bug! If I start making multiple fast refreshes on url www.mysite.com/news (F5, F5, F5, F5, F5...) the basic auth window pops out and asks the password :( Why it is happening so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved. mod_evasive after IP address block doesn't show 403 Forbidden but runs basic auth if it is configured in .htaccess file.